# JPA: set default value when remove relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a self joined entity Authority joined by parent id, I modify the entire family tree just by modify the root, creating and modifying a tree node works well, but when I delete a node, jpa set the entity's parent id to null, in consideration of the database performance, I use not null in every columns, as a result, it brings an MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: **Column 'parent_id' cannot be null**. The SQL is `update t_authority set parent_id=null where parent_id=?`.

So, my question is, why the default value `0L` I set to `parentId` not works? What should I do to make it use the default value in `parentId` when removing the relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_authority")
@SQLDelete(sql =
        "UPDATE t_authority " +
        "SET status = " + DB_STATUS_NOT_EXISTS +
        " WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "status = " + DB_STATUS_EXISTS)
public class Authority implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "authority_name")
    private String authorityName;

    @Column(name = "authority_Id")
    private String authorityId;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Long parentId = 0L;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @Where(clause = "status = " + DB_STATUS_EXISTS)
    private Set<Authority> childAuthorities;
```

mysql table

```
create table `t_authority` (
    `id` bigint unsigned not null primary key auto_increment,
    `authority_name` varchar(100) not null default '' comment 'authority name',
    `authority_id` varchar(100) not null default '' comment 'authority id',
    `parent_id` bigint unsigned not null default 0 comment 'parent id'
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8 collate=utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: "Default value" of parentId is at the class level. It is only used when you create a new instance of Authority (new Authority ()), if it changes and becomes null at some point, it will remain null, it will never return to the initial value (construction moment).

And when it comes to objects managed by the JPA provider, this value is always ignored.

Comment: If an authority doesn't need to have a parent then parent_id should be nullable, you're just making things unnecessary complicated. And if you insist then change the update to set the id to 0L, defaults applies to inserts not updates.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson thanks,  I will consider let it remain null.   Btw, is there any way to delete a child from database after it's parent id become null? Because an orphan can never be used. I have tried `@orphanremoval`, but it dose not work

Comment: @Henrique Fernandes Cipriano                                                    
 Thanks. It looks like I've misunderstood the 'Default value'

Comment: @SeniorCandy, if you only want to clean up your database once I would do it directly in sql.